# Как правильно образовать прилагательное от слова "баск"?

Tags: словообразование

Как обозначить, например, язык басков (кстати, говорят, что он самый сложный): басканский, басканийский или все-таки баскский (но это как-то невыговариваемо)?

Answer (score 5):

Современный вариант - "баскский" (читается [б`асскиj]). Раньше был ещё вариант "басконский", но сейчас слово уже стало устаревшим.

Answer (score 1):

Современный вариант: баскский.См.напр., Википедию.

Answer (score 0):

"Басконский", полагаю, далеко еще вышло из употребления. 
Препятствует нагромождение согласных в баскский, чтение [сск] действительно единственно возможный выход, но такое в целом не характерно для русской орфоэпии  - напоминает ошибку упражняющихся в скороговорках и может ввести в заблуждение.